# how to group identical instances in r into one and at the same time, generate frequency and average stats?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I'm at the last stage of cleaning/organizing data and would appreciate suggestions for this step. I'm new to R and don't understand fully how dataframes or other data types work. (I'm trying to learn but have a project due so need a quick solution). I've imported the data from a CSV file.

I want to group instances with the same (date, ID1, ID2, ID3). I want the average of all stats in the output and also a new column with the number of instances grouped.

Note: ID3 contains . I'd like to rename these to "na" before grouping
I've tried solutions

```
tdata$ID3[is.na(tdata$ID3)] <- "NA"   
tdata[["ID3"]][is.na(tdata[["ID3"]])] <- "NA"
```

But get Error:

```
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(tdata[["ID3"]]), value = c(3L, 3L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

The data is:

```
      date     ID1     ID2     ID3 stat1 stat2 stat.3
1 12-03-07  abc123  wxy456  pqr123    10    20     30  
2 12-03-07  abc123  wxy456  pqr123    20    40     60  
3 10-04-07  bcd456  wxy456  hgf356    10    20     40  
4 12-03-07  abc123  wxy456  pqr123    30    60     90  
5  5-09-07  spa234  int345   <NA>     40    50     70
```

Desired Output

```
date      ID1,     ID2,   ID3,   n, stat1, stat2, stat 3  
12-03-07 abc123, wxy456, pqr457, 3,   20,   40, 60  
10-04-07 bcd456, wxy456, hgf356, 1,   10,   20, 40  
05-09-07 spa234, int345, big234, 1 ,  40,   50, 70
```

I tried this solution: [How to merge multiple data.frames and sum and average columns at the same time in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35007741/how-to-merge-multiple-data-frames-and-sum-and-average-columns-at-the-same-time-i)

But I was not successful merging the columns which have to be grouped and tested for similarity.

```
DF <- merge(tdata$date, tdata$ID1, tdata$ID2, tdata$ID3, by = "Name", all = T)



Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid columns
```

Finally, to generate the n column. Perhaps insert a rows of 1s and use the sum of the column while summarizing?

Comment: Please check your first row of desired output.  The expected mean is different

Comment: My bad, yes, it should be 12-03-07 abc123, wxy456, pqr457, 3, 20, 40, 60

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with `dplyr`.  After grouping by the 'ID' columns, add 'date' and 'n' also in the grouping variables, and get the `mean` of 'stat' columns

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID1, ID2, ID3) %>%
   group_by(date = first(date), n =n(), add=TRUE)  %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(matches("stat")), mean)
```

NOTE: Regarding change the 'NA' to 'big234', we can convert the 'ID3' to `character` class and change it before doing the above operation

```
df1$ID3 <- as.character(df1$ID3)
df1$ID3[is.na(df1$ID3)] <- "big234"
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I appreciate your elegant solution. Didn't imagine it would be a single statement!

Answer (score 1):

While I find the `dplyr` solution proposed by akrun very intuitive to use, there is also a nice `data.table` solution:

Similarly as akrun, I assume that the NA value has been converted to "big234" to get the desired result.

```
library(data.table)
# convert data.frame to data.table
data <- data.table(df1)

# return the desired output
data[, c(.N, lapply(.SD, mean)),
     by = list(date, ID1,ID2, ID3)]
```